# Filter Menu Items by Custom User Role in a page

Tags: menus, user-roles

I want to create a page template where the contents of the menu is filtered. Say, on Template 1, I want only the pages/post created by a custom access role areamanager1 to be displayed on the Menu on all the pages that uses the Template 1. And the same goes with Template 2, etc. At first, I thought of creating a separate menu for each template on the widget panel **BUT** that's not practical for me because it would require the admin to constantly update the menu for each template everytime a new page/post is added. Any ideas on how to implement it? I would really appreciate any help.

Alright, I am thinking if someone knows the dissected version of this function?

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ) ) : ?><?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
```

I think that would help a lot. Cause I can edit the database query to display the posts/pages on the menu widget. Thank you.